# Windows Phone 8 Image Binding

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to bind an image-url to an image control in my Windows Phone 8 app, here's the code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ImageList" SelectionChanged="spotlightListBox_SelectionChanged"  >
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid Width="420">
            <StackPanel Height="325" VerticalAlignment="Top">
               <Image x:Name="eventImage" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            </StackPanel> 
         </Grid>  
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

With this way i get "ag_e_network_error". The ImageUrl is working, I use the same URL in different pages and they work fine. I get the error only in this code. I don't understand the reason of the error. ListBox Itemsource is a generic list.

```
ImageList.ItemsSource = spotlightInfo.Spots;
```

Spots object is a genereic list. And Like this.

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Type { get; set; }
public string Text { get; set; }
public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
```

Image url like `www.someurl.com/someImage.jpg`

Some assistance on where there may be an issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show a more complete, minimal, example of what you're doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the type of **ImageUrl** from string to Uri