# Setting Image Source in a UserControl Button

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

i got an userControl, and i want to set the image button from the page in which userControl is included.

If i set my button image in the usercontrol in this way it works but i can't change.

```
<Button blablabla>
    <Image Source="../../../Assets/truck-512.png"/>
</Button>
```

So i define a property from the codebehind

```
    public ImageSource ButtonSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(SourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Source.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(TruckFormUC),null);
```

and in my userContol xaml i set my image as following

```
<Image x:Name="imgIcon" Source="{Binding Path=ButtonSource}"/>
```

than i use my userControl in my page and i try to set the image source, but it doesn't work

```
    <UC:TruckFormUC x:Name="truckForm"  
 ButtonSource="../../../Assets/truck-512.png"/>
```

Thanks a lot

---

The userControl and the page are in the same folder.

Comment: You shouldn't  need an dependency property.  Only inotiftypropertychanged. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021149/windows-phone-8-image-binding

Comment: My UserControl in not only a button, how can i set the ButtonSource property from the other page? i can't use <UC:MyUserControl Source="">

Comment: UserControls can accept bindings from the data context that is current as well. It's not required to "pass them" through.

Comment: So, i set the image source in the button as suggested `<Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" />`  where ImageUrl is a Uri.   in my page (where the userControl is included) how can i set the path of the image?

Answer (score 1):

Your binding is looking for ButtonSource property on the DataContext object. If you want to bind to your UserControl you should use relative binding.

```
<Image x:Name="imgIcon" Source="{Binding 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UC:TruckFormUC}, 
Path=ButtonSource}"/>
```

See [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms743599%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) markup extension MSDN article for more info

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to use element binding.

```
<Image x:Name="imgIcon" Source="{Binding ElementName=truckForm, Path=ButtonSource}"/>
```