# displaying images from server in a list box

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding, windows-phone

On Windows Phone 8 I have a page that loads user places. Each place consists of name and image name. I then search for the image in the storage and display it. All of that is viewed in a list box using data binding. I do not know how to set the image source in the data binding. Should I make an extra variable of type bit image in the `Place` class, or in the `get` of string image name should I call the function which returns a bit image?

Here is the `Place` class:

```
 class Place
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string user_id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string radius { get; set; }
        public string longitude { get; set; }
        public string latitude { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail { get; set; }


        public async Task<placesobj> getUserPlaces(string userId)
        {
            var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
               new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("id", userId),
               new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("data", "all_places")
            };

            var serverData = serverConnection.connect("places.php", pairs);

            placesobj json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<placesobj>(await serverData);
            if (json  != null)
                return json;
            else
                return null;
        }

        public class placesobj
        {
            public List<Place> places { get; set; }

        }

    }

}
```

And here is the XAML for the list box:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1"  ItemsSource="{Binding places}"  Margin="0,10,0,0" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <StackPanel Margin="10,0,10,8">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10,0,10,8">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="50" />
                                <Image Source="{Binding }"
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think this will be fine . this is working for me.
[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19021149/windows-phone-8-image-binding)

Image source is expecting a uri . so better give this as uri

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>

 public Uri Image { get; set; }
```